# Validar código postal con javaScript

Tags: javascript, validación

¿Comó puedo validar un código postal?, es decir, si hay una longitud exacta o algo que valide que en realidad es un código postal, esto ya sea por medio de una expresión regular o de otra manera, pero usando JavaScript.

Comment: *Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de validar un código postal* Respuesta: Sí, si hay. ¿Alguna otra pregunta? :)

Comment: Esta pregunta definitivamente debiera indicar el país para el que se pretende validar. Estoy seguro que no es lo mismo validar un código postal en Estados Unidos que en el Reino Unido, por ejemplo.

Comment: @jachguate Segun yo tenia entendido un CP constaba de 5 digitos, aunque en diferentes paises significaban diferente las posiciones era valido 0-99999, pero encontre en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_postal) que efectivamente tienes razon, por ejemplo argentina tiene 8 digitos

Comment: de hecho en argentina el código postal tiene 2 formatos uno corto A9999 que ubica la provincia y la zona y uno largo que indica provincia, zona, la manzana (o bloque) y el lado de la manzana) A9999AAA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esta expresión `^\d{4,5}$` indica que solo es valida si se compara contra 4 o 5 dígitos. (Caso para méxico)

Ya que los códigos postales, suelen escribirse sin 0 al principio en algunas ocasiones por ejemplo `4522 = 04522`.

Pero la única forma de saber si un código postal existe de verdad es que tengas una base de datos o un archivo con los del país que necesitas y los compares contra este.

Si quieres una solución javascript pura, podrías usar un arreglo en un json:

```
[   1050,
    2050,
    3050,
    4050,
    12000,
    18010,
    25010,
    33050,
    44504,
    50900
]
```

Y solo necesitas un ciclo para encontrarlo

```
for(var i = 0; i < codigos_postales.length; i++)
{
  if(codigos_postales[i] == valor_ingresado)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Ahora hay un problema, ya que esta búsqueda tiene una complejidad `O(n)`, si el usuario busca el cp 99999, tendrá que recorrer toda la lista, de muchos registros, así que podríamos optar por una [búsqueda binaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_b%C3%BAsqueda)

```
function binarySearch(arreglo, buscado) {
    var m = Math.floor(arreglo.length / 2);


    if (arreglo[m] === buscado) {

        return true;
    } else if (arreglo[m] < buscado && arreglo.length > 1) {

        return binarySearch(arreglo.splice(m, Number.MAX_VALUE), buscado);
    } else if (arreglo[m] > buscado && arreglo.length > 1) {

        return binarySearch(arreglo.splice(0, m), buscado);
    } else {

        return false;// no se encuentra
    }

}
```

> Nota: Necesitas que los datos de tu arreglo, esten ordenados

Answer (score 1):

Si lo unico que quieres es validar que el texto que se ingresa corresponda al formato de un codigo postal solo necesitas crear una expresion regular.

Pero si lo que quieres es saber si ese cadena con formato aceptado por tu expresion de codigo postal, tendrias que consumir los datos de algun lado,
buscando un poco encontre la siguiente api (Codigos postales de Mexico)

https://github.com/Munett/API-Codigos-Postales

la cual solo tendrias que solicitar mediante una peticion ajax y ver si ese texto tiene un lugar asociado, ya lo demas dependeria de la logica de tu aplicacion, de acuerdo a lo que quieras realizar

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quizá quieres validar que el CP ingresado exista y no sea falso o inventado, en alguna ocasión quise implementar eso y me funcionó descargando la DB de [SEPOMEX](http://www.sepomex.gob.mx/servicioslinea/paginas/ccpostales.aspx), lo malo es que la actualizan seguido y borran o añaden nuevos CP, lo recomendable es una expresión regular:

```
^\d{4,5}$
```

Y utilizando el método `.test()` quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
var cp = 56530;
/^\d{4,5}/.test(cp); // true
```

Una función más completa que yo creé para validar el CP y que a la fecha me funciona a la perfección es la siguiente:

```
function validCpMx (a) {
    return a.length > 4
           && /^\d{5}$/.test(a)
           && 12345 != a
           && !/0{5}/.test(a)
           && !/1{5}/.test(a)
           && !/2{5}/.test(a)
           && !/3{5}/.test(a)
           && !/4{5}/.test(a)
           && !/5{5}/.test(a)
           && !/6{5}/.test(a)
           && !/7{5}/.test(a)
           && !/8{5}/.test(a)
           && !/9{5}/.test(a);
}
```